# Selecting links using attribute with multiple patterns

Tags: jquery

I am trying to exclude links which are

either like this `href="#someLink"` or like this `href="javascript:void(0)"`

I am using this jquery selector

```
$("a:not(a[href^='#','javascript'])")
```

which is not working, How can I put ***or*** condition for the href attribute check.

I tried other patterns also like

```
$("a:not(a[href^='#'] || a[href=^'javascript'])").on("click",function(event){
...
});
```

but none worked, Please help.

**Note:** I'm using `:not` because I want to target links other than those type of links.

Comment: People who are downvoting, please explain the reason so that I'll update the question if any confusion is there.

Comment: Create handler function as `function onclick(e){...}` and then `$("a:not(a[href^='#'])").on("click",onclick); $("a[href^='javascript']").on("click", onclick);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

As you said, you want jquery function to execute when you click other than `<a>` then:

```
$("a:not([href^='#']), a:not([href=^'javascript'])").on("click",function(event){
...
});
```

No need to use `||` (OR) operator as you can see here, I have used multiple selectors and it will work like OR condition.

Comment: I'm trying on that, somehow I figured out the same approach.

Comment: Tell me if this works for you and solved your problem.